# Turn off CamelCase for property names on c# objects

Tags: swagger-ui

This is the DTO C# class:

```
public class WeatherForecast
        {
            public string DateFormatted { get; set; }
        }
```

This is what is generated in the swagger definition:

```
{"WeatherForecast":{"type":"object","properties":{"dateFormatted":{"type":"string"}}}}
```

The problem is that when I generate an XML example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<WeatherForecast>
    <dateFormatted>string</dateFormatted>
</WeatherForecast>
```

The problem is that when I send that XML back to the API, it does not populate the DateFormatted property. If I change the case so that it is no longer CamelCase (DateFormatted) it works properly, and the property is populated with "string".

How do I switch off CamelCase when generating the swagger definition?

Answer (score 1):

In aspnet the camelcase properties name by default so you change `Startup` from

```
services.AddMvc();
```

to

```
services
        .AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());
```

Reference: [aspnet](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/194)